# C# How To download Image (BLOB file) from MySql database to my computer as JPEG file?

Tags: arrays, image, winforms, download, blob

I can download Images from PictureBox images, But I cannot download image from database after converting it to normal image

DataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].value    contains an Image that has been converted from Blob to Image(Bitmap)

What I want:--->

```
//I have a DataGridView dgv
//it has 3 columns    id,name,image

//working
pictureBox11.Image = dgv.Rows[0].Cells[2].value as Image;

//Working
pictureBox11.Image.Save("C:\files\Image.jpg",ImageFormat.Jpeg);

//Not Working:   I want this to work
(dgv.Rows[0].Cells[2].value as Image).Image.Save("C:\files\Image.jpg",ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

```
//A function for converting Image to byte array
 public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
        {
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
        }
```

The code that works with an Image that has path such as "C:\files"

```
//working
               string filename = "C:\files\image.jpg";
                
                using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    
                    byte[] image_byte = ImageToByte(pictureBox11.Image);
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image_byte);
                    Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
                    
                    img.Save(fstream , ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    ms.Close();
                    fstream.Close();
                }
```

This is also working, and the pictureBox can show the image

```
//Working
pictureBox11.Image = datagridview1.Rows[0].Cells[2].value as Image;
```

The code that does not work with Blob file downloaded into a DataGridView  image cell

```
//Not Working
               string filename = "C:\files\image.jpg";
                
                using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    
                    byte[] image_byte = ImageToByte(datagridview1.Rows[0].Cells[2].value as Image);
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image_byte);
                    Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
                    
                    img.Save(fstream , ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    ms.Close();
                    fstream.Close();
                }
```

I have searched a lot in internet and changed the code a lot, is always gives Error

'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Comment: It's hard to understand why do you need to convert to byte[] an Image (`ImageToByte(pictureBox11.Image);`: btw, `ImageConverter` just saves the Image to a MemoryStream and returns `MemoryStream.ToArray()`), to then pass the bytes to a MemoryStream (again) to then get back a new Image (again) to finally save it to disc (what you mean for *download*, probably). Why not just save the Image you have directly? What is the actual content of the DGV Cell? What is the data type of the database field? Do you know the actual ImageFormat of these images or you don't care?

Comment: Note that you can pass a byte array that represents an Image to the DataGridView and it will be converted to Image automatically (the DGV will create an ImageColumn to present the byte array as Image), so you can remove all those not-so-useful conversions. To get an Image from a byte array you just need `Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(byte[]))`

Comment: @Jimi  I have changed the code alot, I am not sure which way is the right way. But All I want is   to get a Blob File from mysql database and save it as an image in my computer.

Comment: What is a *Blob File*? Have you stored the Images as a byte array in your database (what a *Blob* would imply)? If so, you just need `File.WriteAllBytes()`.

Comment: Blob is a type of data in database,  we have  varchar, int, blob, and many other in database.  blob is used to store  byte arrays (byte[]), and it can be used to store images in database as byte array.   But, when you want to get that image from database, you have to  convert the byte array to image file.

Comment: @Jimi my problem is,  althouth I can convert the byte array to an image, I cannot save the image in my computer.  What is Wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem.

I basically used the byte array at the first place which is a DataTable instate of using datagridview.
and used File.WriteByte to store the byte of the image file

```
          string connection_str="";
           MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection_str);
            con.Open();

            string command = "command test";

             MySqlDataAdapter cmd = new MySqlDataAdapter(command, con);
          
            DataTable dt_imgs = New Datatable();
            cmd.Fill(dt_imgs);
           
          //the fixed part
           for (int i = 1; i < dt_imgs.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                
                string filename = "C:\files\image"+i.ToString()+".jpg";
                 
                byte[] ImagemByte = (byte[])dt_imgs.Rows[i][3];
                File.WriteAllBytes(filename, ImagemByte);
            }
```